# using macros to condense code

Tags: c++, macros

I am instantiating various objects based on an xml file. To create an object from a template I specify the datatype in the xml file. As I have quite a lot of templates and datatypes that should be supported I'd like to condense my code a little bit. I thought I could do this by using macros, but since I never really used to them, I have no idea how to do this. By providing a list of datatypes I'd like to support I thought I could simply write

```
  MACRO(A, dataTypes)
```

instead of:

```
if(s == "float")
{
    return new A<float>(name); 
}
else if(s == "int")
{
    return new A<int>(name); 
}
else if(s == "bool")
{
    return new A<bool>(name); 
}
else if(s == "std::string")
{
    return new A<std::string>(name); 
}
...
```

But how can I define a macro like that?
The code should compile on Android as well, so it should not rely on another library like boost.

Comment: Instead of `MACRO(A, 'string')`, just write `A<string>`.

Comment: I'd like to know how I can define a macro, that creates all thes if's and elseif's based on a list of strings and a template.

Comment: Why? A system where type information is carried in strings separate from the values is a badly designed one. Use the type system that C++ already gives you.

Comment: As I said, I am using xml files to store my application configuration. I need this so that I don't have to recompile the whole application if I change something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro would be something like:

```
#define MACRO(T) if (s == #T) { return new A<T>(blockName); }
```

You only need a parameter (the type), because as far as I can see, `A` is fixed in your code.

If you want to create the code for several types at once, this is not that easy. You should use something like boost preprocessor.

Comment: I'd like to use it with a list of datatypes though. If I use macro like this I still have to add an additional elseif everywhere whenever I'm using a new datatype. How would it work with boost preprocessor? Would the code still compile on Android?

Comment: I had a look at boost preprocessor. There are plenty of classes I'd have to include in my project. Especially for android this not really a 'lightweight' solution.

Comment: Note that boost.preprocessor is just a header-only (no classes) library, so it may even not be noticed by the Android system apart from the preprocessor itself.